# Give installed module a new name

Tags: python, module, setuptools

I want to install two versions of the same module in site-packages but want to call one 'deprecated_Bio' and the other 'Bio'

using Biopython installation

```
python setup.py install
```

of course creates a nice module Bio for you under lib/site-packages/Bio

is there a way where I can take a past version and name 'deprecated_Bio' in the same lib/site-packages/deprecated-Bio using setuptools so they can can co-exist one being called with

```
import Bio
```

and the other being called with

```
import deprecated_Bio
```

Possible duplicate but I just can't seem to find the answer !

Comment: I guess i could just go in there and change it by hand...but that seems a little hamfisted.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear *why* you want the libraries to co-exist. Do you need to have access to both types of functions within the same program, or are you testing a new library and might want to roll back? If the latter, one approach is [virtualenv](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/), which will allow you to install multiple libraries, and even Python interpreters on the same machine.